# What are the reduceAdd, reduceSum , reduceRemove functions in crossfilter? How should they be used?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

Can someone explain in simple terms how reduce function with its arguments `reduceAdd`, `reduceSum`, `reduceRemove` works in `crossfilter`?

Comment: i'd like to know what the reduceAdd, reduceRemove functions do, specifically and what the arguments passed to them specify

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Remember that map reduce reduces a dataset by keys of a particular dimension. For example lets use a crossfilter instance with records:

```
[
    { name: "Gates",      age: 57,   worth: 72000000000, gender: "m" },
    { name: "Buffet",     age: 59,   worth: 58000000000, gender: "m" },
    { name: "Winfrey",    age: 83,   worth:  2900000000, gender: "f"   },
    { name: "Bloomberg",  age: 71,   worth: 31000000000, gender: "m"  },
    { name: "Walton",     age: 64,   worth: 33000000000, gender: "f"  },
]
```

and dimensions name, age, worth, and gender. We will reduce the gender dimension using the reduce method.

First we define the reduceAdd, reduceRemove, and reduceInitial callback methods.

`reduceInitial` returns an object with the form of the reduced object and the initial values. It takes no parameters.

```
function reduceInitial() {
    return {
        worth: 0,
        count: 0
    };
}
```

`reduceAdd` defines what happens when a record is being 'filtered into' the reduced object for a particular key. The first parameter is a transient instance of the reduced object. The second object is the current record. The method will return the augmented transient reduced object.

```
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    p.worth = p.worth + v.worth;
    p.count = p.count + 1;
    return p;
}
```

`reduceRemove` does the opposite of `reduceAdd` (at least in this example). It takes the same parameters as `reduceAdd`. It is needed because group reduces are updated as records are filtered and sometimes records need to be removed from a previously computed group reduction.

```
function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    p.worth = p.worth - v.worth;
    p.count = p.count - 1;
    return p;
}
```

Invoking the reduce method would look like this:

```
mycf.dimensions.gender.reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial)
```

To take a peek at the reduced values, use the `all` method. To see the top n values use the `top(n)` method.

```
mycf.dimensions.gender.reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial).all()
```

The returned array would (should) look like:

```
[
    { key: "m", value: { worth: 161000000000, count: 3 } },
    { key: "f", value: { worth:  35000000000, count: 2 } },
]
```

The goals of reducing a dataset is to derive a new dataset by first grouping records by common keys, then reducing a dimension those groupings into a single value for each key. In this case we grouped by gender and reduced the worth dimension of that grouping by adding the values of records that shared the same key.

The other reduceX methods are convience methods for the reduce method.

For this example `reduceSum` would be the most appropriate replacement.

```
mycf.dimensions.gender.reduceSum(function(d) {
    return d.worth;
});
```

Invoking `all` on the returned grouping would (should) look like:

```
[
    { key: "m", value: 161000000000 },
    { key: "f", value: 35000000000 },
]
```

`reduceCount` will count records

```
mycf.dimensions.gender.reduceCount();
```

Invoking `all` on the returned grouping would (should) look like:

```
[
    { key: "m", value: 3 },
    { key: "f", value: 2 },
]
```

Hope this helps :)

Source: https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference

Comment: @IsiomaNnodum Can I add more arguments to reduceAdd and reduceRemove functions for some specific modification?

Comment: @PulkitMittal You cannot add any more arguments to those functions. The p represents the current state of the total reduce operation and the v is the current record that is going to affect the current state in some way. What arguments to you want to add?

Comment: Well I just want to make a multiplication inside the functions which has a multiplication factor that is 'session' dependent.

Comment: @PulkitMittal the parameters of the reduceAdd/Remove functions are a part of crossfilter. Please provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  return p + 0.5 * v;
}

This value 0.5 would be different for each user that access the application and that would be determined from the session. The only issue was that I was defining the function outside the scope of the function in which I was applying the crossfilter, so wasn't able to pass the multiplication factor. Now, I have simply defined the functions in the scope, so it works now.

Comment: @PulkitMittal that is was what I was going to suggest. If you need an external factor, if it is defined within the same closure, it is available to all scopes within it. Heres a quick guide to closures - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: did I miss a step before `mycf.dimensions.gender.reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial)`?what is gender?

Comment: @HattrickNZ - I believe that `mycf.dimensions.gender` is just a dimension that was likely previously defined as `mycf.dimension(function(d) {return d.gender;}`

Answer (score 6):

http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/

```
var livingThings = crossfilter([
  // Fact data.
  { name: “Rusty”,  type: “human”, legs: 2 },
  { name: “Alex”,   type: “human”, legs: 2 },
  { name: “Lassie”, type: “dog”,   legs: 4 },
  { name: “Spot”,   type: “dog”,   legs: 4 },
  { name: “Polly”,  type: “bird”,  legs: 2 },
  { name: “Fiona”,  type: “plant”, legs: 0 }
]);
```

For example, how many living things are in my house?

To do this, we’ll call the `groupAll` convenience function, which selects all 
records into a single group, and then the `reduceCount` function, which 
creates a count of the records.

```
// How many living things are in my house?
var n = livingThings.groupAll().reduceCount().value();
console.log("There are " + n + " living things in my house.") // 6
```

Now let’s get a count of all the legs in my house. Again, we’ll use the `groupAll` function to get all records in a single group, but then we call the 
`reduceSum` function. This is going to sum values together. What values? 
Well, we want legs, so let’s pass a function that extracts and returns the number of legs from the fact.

```
// How many total legs are in my house?
var legs = livingThings.groupAll().reduceSum(function(fact) {
  return fact.legs;
}).value()
console.log("There are " + legs + " legs in my house.")
```

`reduceCount` function creates a count of the records.
`reduceSum` function is the sum values of these records.