# summ all the values of a field using crossfilter?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

given this dataset [here](http://animateddata.co.uk/articles/crossfilter/)

```
Date    Origin  Destination Delay (mins)
03/01/2001 13:05:00 MCI MDW 8
03/01/2001 13:45:00 LAS PHX 95
03/01/2001 18:30:00 LAX PHX 10
03/01/2001 18:30:00 ONT PHX 0
03/01/2001 18:30:00 LAS LAX -9
03/01/2001 18:30:00 LAX OAK 12
03/01/2001 18:40:00 ONT SMF -8
03/01/2001 19:00:00 MDW BNA -1
03/01/2001 19:00:00 OAK LAX -10
03/01/2001 19:00:00 LAS LAX -11
...
```

How do I sum all the values in the `Delay` field? I know there is minus values, I am just using this as an example.

I was thinking of using crossfilter to do this but not sure if there is a simplar way of doing this just writing a javascript function.
for instance I can get the total records/rows with below which is 2692

```
cf.size()
//2692
```

**NOTE** 
Bring up console mode (Ctrl-shift-I) and type `cf.size()`
the crossfilter is already defined in the source code(Ctrl-U) `var cf = crossfilter(data);`

---

### EDIT1

using [d3.sum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/wZVOIfurraw)

```
d3.sum(data,function(d){return d.delay;})
30632
```

using array.reduce - see [JavaScript Array.prototype.reduce](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/javascript-array-reduce) -what is the 0?

```
data.reduce(function(total,d){ return total+ d.delay }, 0)
30632
```

using crossfilter, but this is just using the reduce above on a crossfilter delay dimension`var delayDimension = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d.delay;});`

```
delayDimension.top(Infinity).reduce(function(total,d){ return total+ d.delay }, 0)
30632
```

**NOTE:**

This returns the delay value in the last element:

```
data.reduce(function(total,num){ return num.delay })
165
```

---

### EDIT2

adapting on this: 
[Custom calculated aggregated field in Crossfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211448/custom-calculated-aggregated-field-in-crossfilter)

create a dimension:

```
origin=cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.origin; })
```

create my reduceAdd, reduceMove, and reduceInitial functions:

```
var reduceAdd = function(p, v) {
    p.delay += v.delay;
    return p;
}

var reduceRemove = function(p, v) {
    p.delay -= v.delay;
    return p;
}

var reduceInitial = function() {
    return {
        delay : 0
    }
}
```

Example output from console:

```
var json = origin.group().reduce(reduceAdd,reduceRemove,reduceInitial).orderNatural().top(Infinity);
undefined
json
[Objectkey: "ALB"value: Objectdelay: -1__proto__: Object__proto__: Object, Objectkey: "AMA"value: Objectdelay: 171__proto__: Object__proto__: Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
json[0]
Object {key: "ALB", value: Object}
json[0].value
Object {delay: -1}
```

Another good one here:
[What are the reduceAdd, reduceSum , reduceRemove functions in crossfilter? How should they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767231/what-are-the-reduceadd-reducesum-reduceremove-functions-in-crossfilter-how-s) but still is not exactly what I want, this is summing per category, I want a sum total e.g. expecting an answer of `30632` for all the delay values added together.

---

### EDIT3

got it from the [docs](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-crossfilter_groupAll) below printout from the console:

```
cf.size()
//2692

var reduceAdd = function(p, v) {
    p.delay += v.delay;
    return p;
}

var reduceRemove = function(p, v) {
    p.delay -= v.delay;
    return p;
}

var reduceInitial = function() {
    return {
        delay : 0
    }
}

cf_groupAll=cf.groupAll().reduce(reduceAdd,reduceRemove,reduceInitial)
//Object {}

cf_groupAll.value()
//Object {delay: 30632}

cf_groupAll.value().delay
//30632
```

Comment: Are you planning to use Crossfilter for interactivity? In that case you'd use `group.reduceSum`. The Crossfilter docs cover it here: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduceSum  If you aren't using Crossfilter for interactivity, then I wouldn't use it at all. Just use Array.reduce (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or d3's d3.sum (https://github.com/d3/d3-array#sum)

Comment: tks, i ma trying to use it for interactivity, just trying to get my head around it

Answer (score 1):

You could use an jQuery Selector to get the values of the last column. Then you could use parseInt(STRING, 10) in order to parse the Integer values. Then you could easily count them together.

```
var $elements = $('#data tr.item td:last-child')
var sum = 0
$elements.each(function() {
  var currentValue = parseInt($(this).html(), 10)
  sum += currentValue
})
```

Comment: tks, this just works on the rows in the table `sum
86` would need to get table to show all for this to wrok.